# Get complete SQL table data asynchronously from DB Repository to JQuery file

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I have one JQuery file where I want "Customer" table data in JSON format.
We already have a project structure like this:
JQuery file -> Controller class -> DBRepository class -> call to DB table

Now I want to provide asynchronous call when data getting pulled.
The code will generally be like this:

Controller class:

```
public async Task&ltActionResult&gt GetCustomerDataAsync()
{
...
await call to DBRepository.GetCustomerData();
...
}
```

DBRepository class:

```
public async Task&ltTenantBM&gt GetCustomerData()
{
TenantBM custData = new CustomerBM();
customerData = await scoutDB.Customer.Selectt => new { t.id, t.Name, t.Role});
...
}
```

But somehow its not allowing me to put await call there. Even I am not sure is this a correct code or not. Please let me know the correct syntax to put everything in above format.

Thanks.

Comment: if you put in await then it's not async any more...But the reason is probably that the DB method is not a Task to start with. You can't make something which is not async wait, because, well, you have to wait for it anyway. BTW if you're doing an ajax call in jQuery, then in terms of your browser client, it's already async, and in terms of the server, HTTP requests are effectively processed async anyway. You'd only need an async action if you anticipate lots of calls to this method simultaneously which would cause the thread pool to run out of threads. Not sure you really need to do this at all

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for more on the above.

Comment: @ADyson using `await` does not negate async-ness, it is how you implement async code. And making the ActionResult async allows you to call async code, it will not starve the thread pool, in fact it makes more efficient use of it. You are correct about the repo call probably not being awaitable.

Comment: @Crowcoder I meant that await makes the targeted Task _effectively_ non-async within the context of the enclosing method (i.e. it causes the enclosing method to pause until that awaited Task is finished before continuing). This does not block the thread though, as per the docs. Control is still returned to the caller of the enclosing async method. I'd still question whether any of this is actually necessary though, as per my second link.

Comment: @Crowcoder Also I never said it would starve the thread pool, instead I argued that making it async is only necessary if OP anticipates that sufficient long-running requests would be ongoing simultaneously to make thread starvation a likely outcome. I agree that async makes more efficient use of the threads, but at the cost of a little complexity.  OP has a design decision to make based on their likely operating conditions. My point (and discussed in the MSDN article) is that async API actions don't necessarily deliver improved performance, in fact often there's little discernible advantage.

Comment: @ADyson, async allows otherwise idle threads available to do work. It sounds like you are talking about multi-threading which is not what await is.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, that's entirely my point. It frees up the webserver to respond to more requests by freeing up the worker threads in the pool while the async operation takes place. But unless there's a problem with thread blocking in the first place, it won't noticeably improve performance. Not sure I ever mentioned multi-threading. Use of async  / await does not create a new thread AFAIK, it merely frees up the existing one.